# Wicket: DropDown box with checkboxes for multiple selection

Tags: html, combobox, wicket, checkbox

I need to compactly present multi-selection inside a drop-down box in Wicket by having a check box next to each value in the drop down box. I'm thinking of using ListView with CheckBox and Label as a component for DropDownChoice but then I am not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some javascript library applied to Wicket's ListMultipleChoice (which generates a [select multiple="multiple"] HTML tag. I've found one ([jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/), [hosted at GitHub](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)) implemented as a jQuery plugin, which works very well. Thanks to [@erichynds](http://twitter.com/erichynds)!

The Page class is just a plain-old Wicket page, and all you have to do is to import the scripts/stylesheets, and call a single function (highly configurable):

**HomePage.java:**

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    List<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>();

    public HomePage() {
        add(CSSPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(HomePage.class, "jquery.multiselect.css"));
        add(JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(HomePage.class, "jquery.multiselect.min.js"));

        add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));
        Form form = new Form("form") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
                info(selection.toString());
            }
        };
        form.add(new ListMultipleChoice("list",
            new PropertyModel(this, "selection"),
            Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")));
        add(form);
    }
}
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select").multiselect();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
  <form wicket:id="form">
    <select wicket:id="list"></select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alas Wicket is used to generate HTML, and in HTML there is no facility to have a drop-down with checkboxes. (In Swing or another Windowing UI, this would be possible, and your approach would be correct.)

Take a look on the internet for example code for HTML which can cause a similar effect (e.g. a `<div>` which is shown / not shown when you click on the value you're editing). For example  I found this thread here: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=182976